# Problems with fire rate limiter in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently making a game in python, but problem starts, when I try to limit fire rate. The code that is suposed to shoot every second press blocks shooting completely after first shoot, so I checked how variable is changing and it somehow remains constant, which seems very weird. I tried to google it, but it's very hard for me to even put my problem in correct words for google. Here' s the code:

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and igralec.fire_rate % 2 == 1:
        strel.play()
        print(igralec.fire_rate)
        igralec.fire_rate += 1
        if igralec.fire_rate == 6:
            igralec.fire_rate = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you increment/change `igralec.fire_rate` somwhere else, there is no way this code could work. I assume that you do not change it elsewhere or you would have included that code so the issue could be diagnosed.

```py
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and igralec.fire_rate % 2 == 1:
        strel.play()
        print(igralec.fire_rate)
        igralec.fire_rate += 1
        if igralec.fire_rate == 6:
            igralec.fire_rate = 1
```

You can only get into this block if `igralec.fire_rate % 2 == 1`, so `igralec.fire_rate` has to be odd. Then it increments `igralec.fire_rate` to be an even number and can never enter this code block again.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```py
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        if igralec.fire_rate % 2 == 1:
            strel.play()
        print(igralec.fire_rate)
        igralec.fire_rate += 1
        if igralec.fire_rate == 6:
            igralec.fire_rate = 1
```

So it will only call `strel.play()` when `igralec.fire_rate` is odd, but still increment and otherwise manage `igralec.fire_rate` when the space bar is pressed.